# regex to validate the string and return the value in JAVA

Tags: java, regex

I have a string

```
String str = "//contains(@class, 'abc')])[1]//*[@name='xyz']";
```

I tried with below but no luck

```
"\\)\\[\\d*\\]"
```

I need to verify if this string contains ")[number only as many times like 2, 22 etc]" then only I need to take out that number which is in between the square brackets like in above example its :- 1

Comment: You can try this `(?<=\)\[)(\d+)(?=\])` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/NC2xby/1/)

Comment: That seems a valid regular expression that fulfills your requirements. Although you didn't use capturing groups to extract digits only, what did prevent you from removing trailing and leading non-digit characters from its output?

Comment: thanks its working fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
\)\[(\d+)\]
```

- `\)\]` - Matches `)[`
- `(\d+)` - Capturing group matches digits one or more time
- `\]` - Matches `]`

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/NC2xby/2/)

One alternate is using lookaround

`(?<=\)\[)(\d+)(?=\])`

Comment: @asinha always happy to help :)